# Console Application stopped working

Tags: c#

Is it possible for code to work perfectly on the Administrator profile and not work at all while logged in as another user?

I am building certain applications at work, and while developing, coded and tested while logged on as Administrator. Every application working normally.

Now before deployment, when I execute the same application, but now logged in with a specific user account, I just get the error "Console Application stopped working" etc etc. I have handled all possible exceptions with my own Message Box, but this error is something I did not expect?!

In the exe's, I tried changing setting to "Run as Administrator", no use!

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

PS - There are certain FTP methods I reuse from another class. And by handling all possible exceptions, I mean, I would have a try-catch block for the FTP method, so in case of error encountered after deployment, affected user may call helpdesk and notify the exact error.

Comment: Maybe you are accessing paths on the filesystem which are not accessible for another user

Comment: Is there already some code in the application? If it is please post it or link it.

Comment: Just a dumb check, are you referencing any libraries in your project? If you are this also happens when the references are missing on the user's computer.

Comment: "I have handled all possible exceptions with my own Message Box" - that doesn't sound good. It's not generally a good idea to tie console applications to windows UI (it limits their reuse from e.g. scheduled jobs). Also, letting the exception come all of the way out and crash the application might be more useful (especially now whilst you're trying to diagnose this issue).

Comment: I googled your message "Console Application stopped working" and your the only one showing, are you sure this is not a custom message from your app ? can you remove all the try/catch in your app an add one only in your static Main function, so you'll be sure that you're not swallowing any exception.

Comment: Pardon me, I am a novice in .Net Programming. Well yes, I do use/ reference a class and have included the .dll in the same folder as the executable. Maybe I am doing something wrong there? I do have the code, but I cannot post it due to Privacy issues. I will do post what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Remi - Well technically the namespace is ConsoleApplication1, Error is :  "Consoleapplication1 stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program"

Comment: Well, its not the right way to go, but right click and run as Admin, works butter smooth. Should I go ahead and modify all executables to - Run as Administrator under Properties->Compatibility??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Well, its not the right way to go, but right click and run as Admin, works butter smooth. Should I go ahead and modify all executables to - Run as Administrator under Properties->Compatibility??`

You should firstly investigate if your application does need Admin rights indeed. A few scenarios that I can think of where an App needs admin rights are writing to protected locations of the system, writing to registry (excluding the areas that the user has rights on). If you think that admin access is not needed, you could always seek other ways to make it work. For example, instead of writing to a protected location, create a directory for you application in the user's application data folder and write to that location.

Comment: Well indirectly yes, it calls further scripts, which do play around with the registry.

Comment: Well it turned out it did need Admin privileges. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the application, if you're running on I believe Windows Vista or higher(7 works this way for sure)

You can Right click on the application and click on `Run as Administrator`

And yes, Sometimes the application won't work if you're not running as an administrator.  For instance, If it's trying to change files in a protected location.

There are other variances that can cause your program to not work,  For me, `"Console Application stopped working"` normally means that you don't have the right version of the .net framework installed, but it can mean any number of things.

Comment: It is on Windows7, and it is an exe that is included in Startup. So it runs in the background once the user logs on. With regards to framework, same code (exe) works on the same system but on the Administrator profile, but does not work on a specific user account. Is it still a framework issue?

Comment: @user1620230  You probably want to set up some logging to see exactly what goes wrong. and where it goes wrong.  From the sound of it, You're probably going to have to find some way to register your app with the system so that it knows that your app  has Administrator privleges.

Comment: Well, its not the right way to go, but right click and run as Admin, works butter smooth. Should I go ahead and modify all executables to - Run as Administrator under Properties->Compatibility??